# Bodymovin: you create multiple Json exports/animations and only reference one player

Tags: javascript, json, bodymovin

I have 4 bodymovin animations to put on a website.
Currently I am uplaoding the player with each animation/json export.
do I need to do this or can I just included the player once and then the Individual Jsons will use this player to keep file sizes down.

Kind
Regards

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You only need to load bodymovin.js once. I use angular, so I load it on init and save it as a module const, then I inject it anywhere I need. If your'e not using a framework, save it globally.
Each animation should be initiated separately using `loadAnimation()` and give it the container it uses. This needs to be done after the page loads because you need to find the container element.
Also, I believe the best practice is to save all JSON files on a CDN and reference them in your animation configuration `.path` property ant not include them in your website.